# Play framework problema com form

Tags: java, play-framework

## Introdução

Estou começando a desenvolver com o Play Framework. Estou fazendo um modelo de lista TODO com ele.

## Problema

Quando estou instanciando meu form no controller ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém saberia qual é o problema?

#### Controller ( Application.java )

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import play.data.*;
import play.data.Form;

import views.html.*;

import models.*;

public class Application extends Controller {
    static Form<Task> taskForm = form(Task.class);

    public static Result index() {
        return redirect(routes.Application.tasks());
    }

    public static Result tasks() {
        return TODO;
    }

    public static Result newTask() {
        return TODO;
    }

    public static Result deleteTask(Long id) {
        return TODO;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mude:

```
form(Task.class);
```

Para:

```
Form.form(Task.class);
```

**Ou** se preferir, importe estaticamente os métodos de Form assim:

```
import static play.data.Form.*;
```

E continue usando do jeito que você fez.

Comment: era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 1):

Coloque `Form.form(Task.class);` no lugar do erro.

Nesse link tem um exemplo de um CRUD com master-detail: [Play Crud Master-Detail](https://github.com/Alfaville/Master-Detail-Play-Framework-2.3.5)